# Configuring the AWS SDK for Java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-ses

After configuring the **AWS SDK for Java** (v1.3.8), I want to test everything by running their **AWSJavaMailSample**.

After double checking that the following are true:

1. signed up for SES;
2. verified a sender address and sent test message from the AWS console;
3. having production access;
4. added  the `accessKey` and the `secretKey` to the **AwsCredentials.properties** file, from https://aws-portal.amazon.com/gp/aws/securityCredentials

I get an [**InvalidClientTokenId**](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/STS/latest/APIReference/CommonErrors.html): *the AWS Access Key ID provided does not exist in the AWS records*.

```
[AmazonSimpleEmailService]$ java AWSJavaMailSample
Exception in thread "main" Status Code: 403, AWS Service: AmazonSimpleEmailService, AWS Request ID: 6db92cf8-8d69-11e1-b872-d1f99982ef22, AWS Error Code: InvalidClientTokenId, AWS Error Message: The security token included in the request is invalid
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:552)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:289)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:170)
    at com.amazonaws.services.simpleemail.AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClient.invoke(AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClient.java:479)
    at com.amazonaws.services.simpleemail.AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClient.listVerifiedEmailAddresses(AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClient.java:214)
    at com.amazonaws.services.simpleemail.AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClient.listVerifiedEmailAddresses(AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClient.java:410)
    at AWSJavaMailSample.verifyEmailAddress(AWSJavaMailSample.java:155)
    at AWSJavaMailSample.main(AWSJavaMailSample.java:75)
```

Where `AWSJavaMailSample.java:75` is the `verifyEmailAddress(ses, FROM);` call.

---

### Update #1, following [shashankaholic's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10295845/341929)

I've created two new users:

1. *ses-test*, attached **AmazonSESFullAccess** user policy
   `{"Statement":[{"Effect":"Allow","Action":["ses:*"],"Resource":"*" }]}`
2. *ses-smtp-user*, with the default **AmazonSesSendingAccess**
   `{"Statement":[{"Effect":"Allow","Action":"ses:SendRawEmail","Resource":"*"}]}`

And I get the same response.

Even after attaching **AdministratorAccess** to *ses-smtp-user*
`{"Statement":[{"Effect":"Allow","Action":"*","Resource":"*"}]}`
still same response:

```
Exception in thread "main" Status Code: 403, 
AWS Service: AmazonSimpleEmailService, 
AWS Request ID: [...], 
AWS Error Code: InvalidClientTokenId, 
AWS Error Message: The security token included in the request is invalid
```

---

What credentials should be used in this case?

Or how should the AWS SDK for Java be configured for AWSJavaMailSample to work?

---

### Update #2:

the problem was how I was declaring the credentials in the **.properties** file

```
accessKey="ACCESSKEY"; # Java-string-like
```

when instead I should have had

```
accessKey=ACCESSKEY
```

Comment: You should add your Update #2 as the answer. That just solved my problem here.

Comment: I really hope you can clarify this question and answer better. Its impossible to understand and use this. Please redo this for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can verify your User Credentials and privileges from IAM console https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home.

Go to users tab, click on user check privileges. You can also generate new SMTP credentials from https://console.aws.amazon.com/ses/home#smtp-settings: in case.

Answer (score 3):

The problem was how I was declaring the credentials in the **.properties** file

```
accessKey="ACCESSKEY"; # Java-string-like
```

when instead I should have had

```
accessKey=ACCESSKEY
```